# Add space between captions (not between the images)

Tags: spacing, subfloats

Hi I'm wondering if its possible to add/increase the space between some `subfloat` `captions`?

Here my Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure} [h]
 \centering

 \subfloat[text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 ]{
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width={0.30\textwidth}]
    {example-image-golden}}} 
 \subfloat[text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 ]{
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width={0.30\textwidth}]
    {example-image-golden}}} 
  \subfloat[text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 ]{
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width={0.30\textwidth}]
    {example-image-golden}}} 

 \subfloat[]{
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width={0.30\textwidth}]
    {example-image}}} 
 \subfloat[]{
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width={0.30\textwidth}]
    {example-image}}}


 \captionof{figure}{Overall Text}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The space should get increased (to make it more readable):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You were adding a space INSIDE the `\subfloat` in front of the image, so the caption was expanding to fill the entire space.  You were NOT adding a space between the `\subfloat`s (presumably `\subfloat` ends with `\ignorespaces`).

I might add that the subcaption package is preferred.  Also, it wouldn't hurt to throw in a `\raggedright`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [h]
 \centering
 \subfloat[text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 ]{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width={0.30\textwidth}]
    {example-image-golden}}}\hfil
 \subfloat[\sloppy text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 ]{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width={0.30\textwidth}]
    {example-image-golden}}}\hfil
  \subfloat[\sloppy text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 ]{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width={0.30\textwidth}]
    {example-image-golden}}} 

 \subfloat[]{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width={0.30\textwidth}]
    {example-image}}}\hfil
 \subfloat[]{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width={0.30\textwidth}]
    {example-image}}}

 \captionof{figure}{Overall Text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This solution uses the subcaption package.  Each subfigure is really just a minipage.  Consequently, `\textwidth` gets redefined inside the subfigure, hence the new length `\imagewidth=0.3\textwidth`.  The `[t]` option aligns the baselines of the first line, which in this case means the images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\newlength{\imagewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [h]
 \centering
 \imagewidth=0.30\textwidth
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{width=0.8\imagewidth,justification=raggedright}%
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{\dimexpr \imagewidth+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-golden}}
    \caption{text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1}
 \end{subfigure}\hfil
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{\dimexpr \imagewidth+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-golden}}
    \caption{text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2}
 \end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{\dimexpr \imagewidth+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-golden}}
    \caption{text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3}
 \end{subfigure}

 \medskip
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{\dimexpr \imagewidth+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image}}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{\dimexpr \imagewidth+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image}}
  \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}

 \caption{Overall Text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: second demo]

Comment: ok thx for that. This gives a bit more space between the images due to using the whole page width. But is there a way e.g. having the subcaption not using 100% of the image with, more like ~80% of the image width? I was hoping for s.th. like this ;)

Comment: It is possible, but not with subfig.